# Radius server not replying to Access-Request from Meraki AP

Tags: windows-server-2016, radius, wifi

I have an AD server setup in AWS on EC2 windows server 2016 instance and configured NPS to use Radius server in order to implement 802.1x authentication over wifi.

I tried to add Radius server on Meraki AP in one of the SSID but packet capture shows that it only answer the first Access-Request and then no reply from Radius server that leads to Fail to add on Meraki AP.

[image]

Comment: packet capture is attached

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar setup as yours and I recently ran into the same issue.  This is what solved the problem for me.  In your Network Policies setting where you specify the Radius Attributes, add the Framed-MTU attribute with a value of 1344 or lower (I used 1000) and that solved the issue for me.  Hope this works for you if you don't already have it resolved.

Comment: It worked right away.
Thanks for the wonderful resolution Gabriel.